# SharedPreferences generating null pointer violation

Tags: android, object, reference, null, sharedpreferences

So I stepped away from working on this little project for a couple of months and now code that was working before is breaking.  Getting:

"Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference"

```
public class incomingPicListener extends IntentService {
    Bitmap photoCapturedBitmap;
    private static final String RESULT_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String URL_SAVE_IMAGE = "http://******";
    String savedTargetZenFolder;
    Boolean imgsaved;
    SSIDdbAdapter ssidDB;

    SharedPreferences saveFolders = getSharedPreferences("FolderPrefs", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = saveFolders.edit();
```

The error comes in on "SharedPreferences saveFolders = getSharedPreferences("FolderPrefs", 0);".  But again, I haven't changed anything.

Did something change in the 2 months since I worked on this?

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing context to getSharedPreferences()

```
SharedPreferences saveFolders = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("FolderPrefs", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = saveFolders.edit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Get your shared preferences from **PreferenceManager**

```
SharedPreferences saveFolders = PreferenceManager.getSharedPreferences("FolderPrefs", 0);
```

> Note: Use PreferenceManager when there is only one shared preference

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the two lines of code were out of place.  Thank you all for the help.